# Laravel 5.1 relationship of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Let's say I have three models:

> - Worker
> - Department
> - Company

A Company has many Departments and a Department has many Workers. Now how can I get all the Workers from the company?

I can get all the departments with

```
Company::find(1)->departments()
```

I can get all the Workers with

```
Department::find(1)->workers()
```

I tried creating a method to the model Company like that:

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->departments->map(function($item, $key){
        return $item->workers;
    });
}
```

The issue rose, when I wanted to call a the method `'where()'` on the collection with three arguments and it gave me an empty collection.

```
Company::find(1)->workers()->where('salary', '>=', '100');
```

And that returns an empty collection whatever I do. I tried whereLoose, passed '100' as an integer. The following works fine:

```
Company::find(1)->workers()->where('salary', '100');
```

Gives me all the workers, who have a salary of 100.

Is there a way to kind of use the Relationships so I can get the Relationship from `Company->hasMany('Worker')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about hasManyThrough (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). Add function to Your Company model:

```
public function workers()
{
    // hasMany Workers through Department
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Worker', 'App\Models\Department'); 
}
```

so now You're able to do:

```
$Company = Company::with('workers')->find(1);
$Workers = $Company->workers;
```

**a little bonus**. to get data through 2 models, something like hasManyThrough+hasMany (not tested):

create class (file in models directory):

app/Models/ExtendedModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExtendedModel extends Model {
    public function hasManyThrough2Models($model1, $model2, $model3, $model1Key, $model2KeyWith1, $model2Key, $model3KeyWith2)
    {
        $model1 = new $model1;
        $model1Table = $model1->getTable();
        $model2 = new $model2;
        $model2Table = $model2->getTable();
        $model3 = new $model3;
        $model3Table = $model3->getTable();

        return $model1
            ->join($model2Table, $model2Table . '.' . $model2KeyWith1, '=', $model1Table . '.' . $model1Key)
            ->join($model3Table, $model3Table . '.' . $model3KeyWith2, '=', $model2Table . '.' . $model2Key)
            ->select($model1Table . '.*');
    }
}
```

and then get data through 2 models:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Company extends ExtendedModel {

    public function worksheets() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough2Models('App\Models\Worksheet', 'App\Models\Worker', 'App\Models\Department', 'worker_id', 'id', 'department_id', 'id');
    }
```

now use:

```
$Company = Company::with('worksheets')->find(1);
$Worksheets = $Company->worksheets;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. But is there a way to go through 2 intermediate models? Let's say I have a relationship       
     Worker->hasMany('Worksheet') 

and I'm looking for 

     Company->worksheets().

Comment: I'm not sure that it can be done without raw SQL query with joins. Or we can get the source of hasManyThrough and make our own method and call it hasManyThrough2Models. Wait a little, I'll try to make it. I'll feedback soon.

Comment: @MihkelAllorg, I've updated my answer, hope it helps. warn: not tested, but You can try

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$company = Company::with('departments.workers')->find(1);
```

So, it'll return all the workers who belongs to that company under each department individually. In this case, you may loop like this:

```
@foreach($company->departments as $department)

    {{ $department->name }}

    @foreach($department->workers as $worker)

        {{ $worker->name }}

    @endforeach;

@endforeach;
```